# What to do if the parameter of a function is not defined? (PHP)

Tags: php, optional-parameters

I have `static function getQuery(isset($var)?$var:$var="no")` which does not work.

I want to use it either by `DoDb::getQuery();` or `DoDb::getQuery($var);` depending on the necessities.

Comment: So you want to preset the parameter with a default value, correct?

Comment: $Pekka, in case it is not called with a parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
static function getQuery($var="no")
```

Comment: will I'll be able to pass "yes"? Like $var="yes"; DoDb::getQuery($var);

Comment: "yes" you can (and all other values you want to)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this page http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/15/5.
This is the same in many language ;)